# Response code 410 in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to load-test a web application using JMeter. I used proxy and then run the test. I am able to login into the application, but for some pages it is giving response `code 410` in J Meter.

I tried to ignore the error by adding Bean Shell Post Processor to the test script by writing the following code in it:

```
if (prev.getResponseCode().equals("410") == true) { 
    prev.setResponseOK(); }
```

However, the response in View Results tree is visible intermediately and the script is getting executed.

I need help to resolve the `410 error`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? Your code should work fine and substitute response code 410 with response code 200. One little enhancement is `== true` bit is not required.

Comment: When I run my test script without the Bean Shell Post Processor or Response Assertion then its is running successfully and giving Response Code 200 however, when I run the test script for more than one user then it gives response code 410 error. Is there any other way to resolve and run my test script successfully? Please assist

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) and check "Ignore Status":

[image]

Comment: I have used Response Assertion however, it is executing but not viewing the results in view results tree. I am getting the below in Sample Results of View Results Tree
Latency: 54
Size in bytes: 298
Headers size in bytes: 298
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 410
Response message: Gone.  Is there any other way to handle this Response code?